# Add SKSpriteNode multiple times but with different location

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I am trying to add the same `SKSpriteNote` four times to the same scene but I can't figure out exactly how to do it.

I found old tutorial but I struggle to implement it successfully in swift.

**GameScene.swift**

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var brick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "brick")

func addBricks(size:CGSize){
    for var i = 0; i < 4; i++ {

        // Brick settings
        self.brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: brick.frame.size)
        self.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

        // Brick positioning
        var xPos = brick.size.width/5 * (i + 1)
        var yPos = brick.size.height - 50
        self.brick.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)

        self.addChild(brick)
    }
}

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.addBricks(size)

    }

}
```

I receive an error in line where I create `var xPos = brick.size.width/5 * (i + 1)`.

The desired end effect I want to achieve is more less like this.

[image]

Please advise, thank you.

Comment: what error? please post the exact error message

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply but I managed to solve it somehow. I posted solution below for future reference if anybody is interested. I am not sure if the code is optimized properly for this task. If you find more sufficient way of doing this, please share. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem, but I am not sure about code optimization... somehow it works :)

If anybody know how to make is simpler, please let me know. Here is the final code.

```
    func addBricks(size:CGSize){
    for var i = 0; i < 4; i++ {

        let brick = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "brick")

        // Brick settings
        brick.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: brick.frame.size)
        brick.physicsBody!.dynamic = false

        // Brick positioning
        var xPos = size.width/5 //CGFloat
        var xPosInt = Int(xPos) * (i + 1) // Int
        xPos = CGFloat(xPosInt) // Convert to CGFloat again
        var yPos = size.height - 50

        brick.position = CGPointMake(xPos, yPos)

        self.addChild(brick)


    }
}
```

And final result as desired.
[image]

Comment: The reason for the error in your original question is because you cannot add a node as a child more than once.  Your original question had `brick`'s declaration as an instance property, and each time you called `addBricks` it was trying to re-initialize and re-`addChild` the same node (not allowed).  In your answer, `brick` is declared as a local variable inside the body of `addBricks` and so it is a different node each time the `addBricks` is called.  The only other solution to adding the same node to a scene multiple times would be to `copy()` the node.